# how to create a stacked bar chart with matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe with some sample data as follows

```
   year_start       party  num_legistators
0         2010    democrat               50
1         2010  republican              133
2         2010     unknown                4
3         2011    democrat               67
4         2011  republican              56
5         2012    democrat               76
6         2012  republican              43
```

I am trying to create a stacked bar chart where the x axis is the `year_start` and the y axis is the `num_legislators` and the color of the stacked bars is `party`

I have done this so far

`df_toviz.plot(x= "year_start", kind='bar', stacked=True)`

[image]

how do I get to be stacked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pivot your data frame first so `party` goes as columns:

[Full example](https://akuiper.com/console/ygC60pgQgVp-)

```
df.pivot('year_start', 'party', 'num_legistators').plot.bar(stacked=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]